# Compiling libpandoc and undefined reference to utf8_table4 in regex-pcre-builtin

Tags: c, haskell

I'm trying to update [libpandoc](https://github.com/toyvo/libpandoc) to the newer versions (above 1.10), and I got everything code-wise fixed (basically ParserState had to be changed to ReaderOptions and the default settings updated).

However, during build, I get the following error:

> Loading package regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.6.8.31 ... linking ... ghc: /home/XXXX/.cabal/lib/regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.6.8.31/ghc-7.4.1/HSregex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.6.8.31.o: unknown symbol `utf8_table4'
>   ghc: unable to load package `regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.6.8.31'

Trying to reinstall `regex-pcre-builtin` I get:

```
$ cabal install regex-pcre-builtin --reinstall
Resolving dependencies...
In order, the following would be installed:
regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.6.8.31 (reinstall)
cabal: The following packages are likely to be broken by the reinstalls:
highlighting-kate-0.5.4
pandoc-1.11.1
Use --force-reinstalls if you want to install anyway.
```

Which says that reinstall may in fact break pandoc itself.

I'm rather new to Haskell, and all my searches for `regex-pcre-builtin` and `utf8_table4` on google leads to postings on hpaste.org where people have pasted the same error.

How can I resolve this issue? What should I look for in such situations?

---

Edit: Here's the offending code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module LibPandoc.Instances where

import Data.Data
import Data.DeriveTH
import Text.Pandoc
import Text.Pandoc.Shared

$( derive makeTypeable ''ReaderOptions )
$( derive makeData ''ReaderOptions )
$( derive makeTypeable ''WriterOptions )
$( derive makeData ''WriterOptions )
$( derive makeTypeable ''HTMLMathMethod )
$( derive makeData ''HTMLMathMethod )
$( derive makeTypeable ''ObfuscationMethod )
$( derive makeData ''ObfuscationMethod )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue recently as well, it seems to be a bug in the most recent release. You can work around this by using the previous release, e.g.:

```
ghc-pkg unregister regex-pcre-builtin
cabal install regex-pcre-builtin-0.94.4.5.8.31
```

Comment: That did it thanks. Note for future visitors: You may need to reinstall a couple of packages that depend on this.